# Which scripture talks about Vidhata Purush?

Tags: scripture

http://www.chitradivakaruni.com/excerpt-sister-of-my-heart/

"They say in the old tales that the first night after a child is born, the Bidhata Purush comes down to earth himself to decide what its fortune is to be. That is why they bathe babies in sandalwood water and wrap them in soft red malmal, color of luck. That is why they leave sweetmeats by the cradle. Silver-leafed sandesh, dark pantuas floating in golden syrup, jilipis orange as the heart of a fire, glazed with honey-sugar. If the child is especially lucky, in the morning it will all be gone."

Apparently the child is left alone for Vidhata Purush to write its fate on its forehead.  Does any scripture talk about this?